# probability calculation approach choice

Tags: probability

So the problem is the following, There are 11 birds , 6 are yellow , 3 are green and two are blue. We randomly form a group of 5 birds taken from these 11 birds. If we pick these birds one after another, what is the probability that the first and the last are yellow? I thought about it for some time and i have arrived at thoughts that it is an ordered probability and it requires permutations, Would it be right if i would calculate it this way:

$6*5*(9*8*7)/11*10*9*8*7$

or should i use this approach:

$6/11*5/11*1/9*1/8*1/7$ ?

Comment: The second way has an error, probably : you meant $\frac 5{10}$ instead of $5 / 11$. (If you think that is not an error, then it is an error in concept) . You need to explain your first answer, I don't understand how you come up with it.

Comment: oh yes thank you, i ment 5/10 its my mistake. My first approach is that there are 6 ways to put the yellow bird on the first place and 5 on the last as one was already taken, and i multiply it by other ways i have for the second third and the fourth place, after that i divide it by symmetric sample space of 11*10*9*8*7 ordered fivesomes

Comment: as we have already taken 2 birds out of 11 we can pick any birds on possition 2,3,4 and as we dont care which bird stands on possition 2,3,4 we can pick one of the remaining ones for these positions? sorry if i am wrong

Comment: No, I just realized : the last probability is not $\frac 5{11}$ if you picked yellow balls somewhere in the middle. You can't place $5$ on the last if you picked some yellow balls in the middle. For example, if you picked yellow balls  every time, then the last time you will have only $2$ yellow balls left, right?

Comment: so, you mean that it would be : $ 6/11 * 5/7 *( 1/10*1/9*1/8)$ ? considering if we dont pick a yellow one in the second third or fourth

Comment: If we don't pick a yellow one in the second third or fourth, it would be $6/11 \times 5/7 \times (5/10 \times 4 /9 \times 3/8)$. The number of non-yellow birds is $5,4,3$ in the second, third and fourth pick, because we don't pick a yellow bird, so we pick one which is not yellow. There are five in the second turn, four in the third turn and three in the fourth turn.